# Check how a file is delimited before reading into R

Tags: r, import

I have a list of files (not made by me) that for some reason are all labelled (".csv") even though some are csv and some are tab delimited. So when I try read them in R, I would have to specify separator manually. Unless, someone knows if there is a way to check this before I get a mangled file read in.

Comment: `fread` in the data.table package makes an attempt to guess the correct separator.

Comment: awesome. Much better than the if(grepl("\t", check.file[1,])[1]) check.file <- read.table(checks[i], header=T, sep="\t" )  I was doing after reading it in as CSV. Thanks Joran!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Should have put this in an answer...

The `fread` function in the package **data.table** makes an attempt to guess the correct separator. It's probably not perfect, but it will likely handle most simple cases.

Answer (score 6):

Since tabs are not particularly likely to be in data unless there as a separator could do this as a usually correct test:

```
dat <- if( "\t" %in% strsplit(readLines("path/fil.csv", n=1)[1], split="")[[1]] ) { 
     read.table("path/fil.csv", sep="\t") }else{
     read.table("path/fil.csv", sep=",") }
```

(Handles only the case of either "\t" or "," as described.) Testing:

```
> dat <- if( "\t" %in% strsplit(readLines(textConnection("a\tb\tc\nd\te\tf"), n=1)[1], split="")[[1]] ) { 
+      read.table(textConnection("a\tb\tc\nd\te\tf"), sep="\t") }else{
+      read.table(textConnection("a,b,c\nd,e,f"), sep=",") }
> dat
  V1 V2 V3
1  a  b  c
2  d  e  f
```